# Error: Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed. SDL/c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, sdl

So I'm new to SDL and in my code I'm getting this error:

> pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed.

Here's the code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include "events.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
SDL_Renderer* ro;
SDL_Texture* to;
SDL_Surface* so;
SDL_Window* wo;


SDL_FreeSurface(so->getImage());

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ro->getRenderer(), 255, 255, 255, 255); // error here

// handle events

events mo;
mo.handleEvents();

// cleanup SDL

SDL_DestroyTexture(to->getTexture()); // error here
SDL_DestroyRenderer(ro->getRenderer()); // error here
SDL_DestroyWindow(wo->getWindow()); // error here
SDL_Quit();

return 0;
}
```

**events.h**

```
#pragma once
class events
{
public:
events();
void handleEvents();
SDL_Renderer* getRenderer();
SDL_Texture* getTexture();
SDL_Surface* getImage();
SDL_Window* getWindow();
~events();
private:
SDL_Event event;
int x;
int y;
bool quit;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;
SDL_Texture *texture;
SDL_Surface *image;
SDL_Window *window;
};
```

**events.cpp**

```
#include "events.h"
#include <SDL.h>


events::events()
{
SDL_Event event;
int x = 288;
int y = 208;
bool quit = false;
SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image);
SDL_Surface *image = SDL_LoadBMP("face.bmp");
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Keyboard/Mouse events", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);
}


events::~events()
{
}

void events::handleEvents(){

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

while (!quit)
{
    SDL_Delay(10);
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);

    switch (event.type)
    {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        quit = true;
        break;

    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
        case SDLK_LEFT:
            x -= 5;
            break;
        case SDLK_RIGHT:
            x += 5;
            break;
        case SDLK_UP:
            y -= 5;
            break;
        case SDLK_DOWN:
            y += 5;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }

    SDL_Rect dstrect = { x, y, 64, 64 };

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &dstrect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
  }
}

SDL_Renderer* events::getRenderer(){
return renderer;
}

SDL_Texture* events::getTexture(){
return texture;
}

SDL_Surface* events::getImage(){
return image;
}

SDL_Window* events::getWindow(){
return window;
}
```

Comment: `SDL_Renderer* ro;
SDL_Texture* to;
SDL_Surface* so;
SDL_Window* wo;`
Are all uninitialized pointers to possibly abstract classes. Didn't you mean creating e.g. `events ev;` and then call `SDL_FreeSurface(ev.getImage());`?

Comment: This is all sorts of wrong. You need to go learn basics of C++ before working with SDL. In your Event constructor you are creating the renderer, texture etc as local variables which will go out of scope when the constructor finishes. The member variables for renderer etc will be uninitialized. Then to top it off you have declared them again in the main function but never assigned anything to them and are calling functions from them which don't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error when compiling `events.cpp` because `events.h` does not include `SDL.h` before it uses SDL data types.  Then in `events.cpp`, you have `SDL.h` included after `events.h`, hence the error.